# ユーザーページで通知があるとタブの下線が消える

Tags: バグ, デザイン

些細なことですが、ユーザーページのタブに通知が来ていると、そのタブの下線が消えます。
またホバーしたり、一度タブを切り替え通知を消せば治ります。
以下の画像では「返信」タブで起こってます。
[image: ユーザーページのタブ]

---

追記：
mac 10.13.1 Firefox 57.0 で確認
同上 Safari 11.0.1 では起こりませんでした

FF側のバグっぽいですかね…

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 上の Google chrome 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64 ビット) および Firefox Quantum 57.0 (64 ビット) で再現しませんでした。環境情報を追記して頂けませんか？

Comment: Mac 10.13.1 Firefox 57.0では起こりますが、他では起こりませんね…
うちの環境限定のバグで、早とちりだったぽいですね。